# VMware Workstation 12 wont compile modules on linux kernel 4.6

Tags: kernel, compiling, vmware, vmware-workstation

I recently had to install kernel 4.6 in my Ubuntu 16.04 to stop the random "suspend" crashes.

After install I ran:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

and got the error:

```
<snip>

from /tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: In function ‘HostIFGetUserPages’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define current get_current()


<snip>
from /tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
#define current get_current()

<snip>

from /tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only/userif.c: In function ‘UserifLockPage’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:17:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
#define current get_current()

<snip>
scripts/Makefile.build:291: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only/userif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1434: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-VKdGcJ/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

VMs wouldn't run with an error regarding been unable to load vmmon

Answer (score 1):

It appears `get_user_pages` was replaced with `get_user_pages_remote`

With this patch: https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/2/10/555

## To resolve:

(From Arch linux wiki:)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#Kernel_modules_fail_to_build_after_Linux_4.6

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar xf vmmon.tar
mv vmmon.tar vmmon.old.tar
sed -i -e 's/get_user_pages/get_user_pages_remote/g' vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
rm -r vmmon-only
tar xf vmnet.tar
mv vmnet.tar vmnet.old.tar
sed -i -e 's/get_user_pages/get_user_pages_remote/g' vmnet-only/userif.c
tar cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmnet-only
```

*To me it seems like this is a linux patch breaking userspace, am I wrong?*

Answer (score 1):

[Prayag Sangode's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600108/424342) on [Before you can run VMware several modules must be compiled - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439529/424342) resolved the issue on Ubuntu 18 (VMware version 15.5).

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
> cd vmware-host-modules
> git checkout workstation-15.5.6
> sudo make ; sudo make install
> ```