# How do I install the vmmon kernel module for VMware?

Tags: 16.04, vmware-workstation

I've recently installed VMware Workstation 12.1.1 build-3770994 and whenever I attempt to open a virtual machine, I recieve the following error:

[image: Vmmon module error window]

When I navigate to /dev/ , there is no vmmon to be found

[image]

When I run the command: `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`, I get this error:

[image]

I've attempted to reinstall VMware several times, but to no avail did the vmmon kernel module load. Is there a soulution to this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/810087/vmware-workstation-12-wont-compile-modules-on-linux-kernel-4-6  does this help?

Comment: I've referred to that, none of the methods have seemed to work.

Comment: What is the error when you run: `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` if there is no error, are the two vmware services running?

Comment: They are still failing to run after I have run the command.

Comment: So two things, firstly you are running the 4.4 kernel, so you shouldn't make the changes here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/810087/vmware-workstation-12-wont-compile-modules-on-linux-kernel-4-6 (if you haven't taken backups of the tar files uninstall and reinstall). After you do this run `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` again, but this time copy the actual make errors (you will have to scroll back up) . the errors will say "warning" probably, they will be a little stack trace before it.

Comment: could it be the same issue than this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328791/vmware-player-unable-to-start-services-in-ubuntu/41778797

Answer (score 4):

Below solution worked for me on Fedora32

I have VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.6-16341506.x86_64.bundle and used the following commands:

git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
cd vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-15.5.6
sudo make ; sudo make install

Comment: I could build the module for vmware workstation 17 from this git repo. but I still cannot load vmmon or use vmware at all. Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem on 22.10 this is the end of

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

```
 Starting VMware services:    
   Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Unable to start services
```

*

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1270388)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).